# What is the best way to concat/merge below two array without disturbing sort order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation, merging-data

example array are as below:

```
   var aa = [{date: "sep", data:[1,2,3]}, {date: "oct", data:[4,5,6]}];
   var bb = [{date: "oct", data:[1,2,3]}, {date: "nov", data:[40,50,60]}, {date: "dec", data:[41,51,61]}];
```

after merging result should look like:

```
  var mergedArray =
 [
{date: "sep", data:[1,2,3]},
{date: "oct", data:[4,5,6,1,2,3]},
{date: "nov", data:[40,50,60]},
{date: "dec", data:[41,51,61]}
]
```

Comment: Just loop over. Show  your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.reduce()` to reduce your two array of objects into an object, where the key for the object is each `date`, and each `date` stores a reference to the entire object. However, if a repeated date occurs (ie: the date already exists in the accumulated object), you can instead `.concat()` the array onto the already existing array. Lastly, using the order array of dates we initially created, you can map your resulting object into an array of merged objects like so:

```js
const aa = [{date: "sep", data:[1,2,3]}, {date: "oct", data:[4,5,6]}];
const bb = [{date: "oct", data:[1,2,3]}, {date: "nov", data:[40,50,60]}, {date: "dec", data:[41,51,61]}];

const merged = [...aa, ...bb];
const order = [...new Set(merged.map(({date}) => date))];

const mergedObj = merged.reduce((acc, {date, data, ...rest }) => {
  acc[date] = acc[date] || {date, ...rest, data: []};
  acc[date].data = acc[date].data.concat(data);
  return acc;
}, {});

const res = order.map(key => mergedObj[key]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in just one for loop.

```js
  
  const aa = [{date: "sep", data:[1,2,3]}, {date: "oct", data:[4,5,6]}];
    const bb = [{date: "oct", data:[1,2,3]}, {date: "nov", data:[40,50,60]}, {date: "dec", data:[41,51,61]}];
    
    let tempArr = aa;
    
bb.forEach(rec => { 
    let findIndex = tempArr.findIndex(obj => obj.date == rec.date);
    if(findIndex==-1){
       tempArr.push(rec);
       } else {
      tempArr[findIndex].data = tempArr[findIndex].data.concat(rec.data);
       }
    });
    console.log(tempArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and group by `date` and get new objects as result set.

```js
var array1 = [{ date: "sep", data: [1, 2, 3] }, { date: "oct", data: [4, 5, 6] }],
    array2 = [{ date: "oct", data: [1, 2, 3] }, { date: "nov", data: [40, 50, 60] }, { date: "dec", data: [41, 51, 61] }],
    result = Array.from(
        [...array1, ...array2].reduce(
            (m, { date, data }) => m.set(date, [...(m.get(date) || []), ...data]),
            new Map
        ),
        ([date, data]) => ({ date, data })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```